# Predict() returns too many values instead of one

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am building a system that recommends a book from a dataset based on what is best for the user. The problem is that not only 1 book is returned to me, but a lot of them come out. How can I solve?

The code is this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors._classification import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd

class SuggestAudiobook:
def __init__(self, book):
            
    model = KNeighborsClassifier()

    book = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", delimiter = ";")

    var2 = book.Title

    var1 = book[["audioRuntime_converted", "category_converted"]]

    var2 = var2.astype('string')
    var1 = var1.astype('int')
        
    model.fit(var1, var2)

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = {"audioRuntime_converted": book.audioRuntime_converted, "category_converted": book.category_converted})

    predictionDataframe = model.predict(dataframe)

    print("L'audiobook recommended for you is --> ", predictionDataframe)
```

The result is this:

```
audiobook recommended for you is' -->  ['Catching Fire' 'In Charge of Moonlight' 'Catching Fire' ... 'Born a Crime' 'Born a Crime' 'Born a Crime']
```

I attach the images of the result obtained:
[image]

I'm going to recommend a book among those included in the dataset based on the data inputs. In this case the data inputs are: `audioRuntime_converted` and `category_converted` (they are found in the other file that calls the function). Then in the dataset I go to search based on those 2 fields. I am sure that the procedure is correct as applied in another project, only problem is the output which gives me more values ​​instead of one.

Comment: Please post the result a text, not image.

Comment: okay i edited and added the result as code in the post

Comment: why do you use the same data for training and testing?

Comment: I'm going to recommend a book among those included in the dataset based on the data inputs. In this case the data inputs are: audioRuntime_converted "and" category_converted "(they are found in the other file that calls the function). Then in the dataset I go to search based on those 2 fields. I am sure that the procedure is correct as applied in another project, only problem is the output which gives me more values ​​instead of one.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple lines in your dataframe, the [`.predict()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict) function will run for every line of your dataset.

So `len(predictionDataframe) == len(dataframe)`

Comment: There's nothing to put anywhere, it's just to show that this is the expected result. You'll have the same number of lines in your input and output dataframe.

Comment: and how can i have only one result?

Comment: Run the .predict on a single row of your dataframe

Comment: Do you know how I can do it? you would really help me

Comment: `model.predict(dataframe.iloc[[0]])` to run on the first line

Comment: okay it worked, but now i have always the same result

Comment: Because this example is only for the first row of your dataframe.

Comment: so, what i have to do? I need only 1 result which is the book recommended and not the all dataframe. I'm going crazy, please help

Comment: We're really getting out of the scope of the question here. You'll need to follow some tutorials to understand what you are doing, I guess:
1. Learn [how to use pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html) 2. Learn [how to use sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: how about this? `for i in range(len(dataframe)): print(model.predict(dataframe.iloc[[i]]))`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what the input in `model.predict(input)`, the prediction will be done for each record in the input. In your code, you seem to have input the training dataset to make a prediction, so the output is also a list of books, likely the same number of rows as the training label (`var2`).

I have simulated some (quite obvious) dataset for the prediction

```
from sklearn.neighbors._classification import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# book = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", delimiter = ";")
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 10, (5,2))), pd.DataFrame(['Book A']*5)], axis=1)
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(5, 15, (5,2))), pd.DataFrame(['Book B']*5)], axis=1)
book = pd.concat([df1, df2])
book.columns = ['audioRuntime_converted', 'category_converted', 'Title']
print(book)

   audioRuntime_converted  category_converted   Title
0                3.180352            1.995319  Book A
1                5.928537            9.304618  Book A
2                3.445036            5.746906  Book A
3                3.623655            2.043251  Book A
4                8.340740            9.641824  Book A
0                7.224949            7.158453  Book B
1                9.191920           10.732677  Book B
2                7.417375            6.956461  Book B
3               10.274473           14.435836  Book B
4                5.945386           13.222845  Book B
```

Next I do the training and prediction:

```
var1 = book[["audioRuntime_converted", "category_converted"]].astype('int').values    #this is X_train
var2 = book.Title.astype('str')                                                       #this is y_train
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(var1, var2)

test_list = [ [1,3], [3,6], [9,7], [10,12] ]    #list of user attributes [x,y]
for user in test_list:
    prediction = model.predict([user])    #input 1 user to get 1 book recommendation
    print(f"L'audiobook recommended for user {user} is --> {prediction}")
```

Output:

```
L'audiobook recommended for user [1, 3] is --> ['Book A']
L'audiobook recommended for user [3, 6] is --> ['Book A']
L'audiobook recommended for user [9, 7] is --> ['Book B']
L'audiobook recommended for user [10, 12] is --> ['Book B']
```

As you can see, if a user has low attributes [x,y], the recommended book is "Book A", whereas if a user has higher attributes [x,y], the recommended book is "Book B".

Also, for the input in `model.predict(input)`, an input of 1 user attribute pair (for example `[1,3]`) gets 1 book recommendation.

**Edit**: You might need to understand the difference between `book.audioRuntime_converted` and `[book.audioRuntime_converted]`. When you wrap a number around `[ ]`, you'd get a list/array/series with 1 element (the difference between list/array/series is another topic). Here's a comparison between the code in the question and your "another code":

```
pd.DataFrame(data={"audioRuntime_converted": book.audioRuntime_converted, "category_converted": book.category_converted })
pd.DataFrame(data={"audioRuntime_converted": [this, is, already, series], "category_converted": [this, is, also, series]})
#that's why output is a series of prediction

pd.DataFrame(data={"audioRuntime_converted":[book.audioRuntime_converted], "average_rating_converted":[book.average_rating_converted], "ratings_count_converted":[book.ratings_count_converted]}) 
pd.DataFrame(data={"audioRuntime_converted":[there is single number here], "average_rating_converted":[ there is single number here ], "ratings_count_converted":[there isa single number here]}) 
#that's why there is only 1 prediction
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But the problem is that, I, putting some input data (such as the duration of the audiobook and the category) I want to find **only 1 book** that I might like given the data entered. so the forecast function should only return 1 value and consequently the dataframe should have only one row (?). In another code I do pretty much the same thing, to predict the price and it works, I don't understand here why it doesn't go.

Comment: if your input is 1 set of features like [1,3], you will get 1 book recommendation. Whereas if your input is for example [ [2,3], [3,6] ], you will get 2 recommendations, 1 for each pair of features

Comment: I just checked: printing the dataframe I get practically as many rows as there are in the dataset, but in reality this shouldn't happen. In fact in the other file I have, if I go to print the dataset I am shown only one line.

Comment: I've edited my answer for better clarity, that 1 user attribute pair gets 1 book recommendation, hopefully it's acceptable to you :-)

Comment: okay i understand what you mean.  I really thank you for the time you are dedicating to me.  The problem is that the solution you told me is not adoptable.  Inside the dataset I have many books, each one different.  I have no users.  The user is practically just me who by writing the 2 values ​​I want to find the most recommended book for me.  I think I have identified the problem and it is that after I do the fit, when I create the dataframe, inside it there are all the rows instead of just 1 row.

Comment: In another code that I have created for the prediction of the price always on the same data everything works perfectly and within the dataframe there is only one row of which I then go to predict the price.  here, on the other hand, this is not the case. I don't understand why.  I am desperate.

Comment: In your other code is a regression problem? There should be many features in the input to get 1 prediction value, am i right? That's why the input has many values in 1 row. The concept is still the same: 1 row of input to get 1 prediction.

Comment: If the user is you, you only need to set your desired features pair: [audioRuntime, category], and then the model will give you a recommendation!

Comment: the other code is literally the same, identical. The code is the same, it just changes that I take the audioRuntime_converted "," average_rating_converted "and the" ratings_count_converted "for the dataframe. And if I print the dataframe there is only 1 line. Here instead I get all the lines of the dataset.

Comment: do you mean this line is the same? `dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = {"audioRuntime_converted": book.audioRuntime_converted, "category_converted": book.category_converted})` Can you show the other code?

Comment: ` @classmethod
def PricePrevision(cls, book):        
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data={"audioRuntime_converted":[book.audioRuntime_converted],"average_rating_converted":[book.average_rating_converted],"ratings_count_converted":[book.ratings_count_converted]})
prevision_var2 = cls.model.predict(dataframe)
print("The price will be --> ", int(prevision_var2), "dollar") ` As you can see, the code is identical ,except I use brackets "[" "]" in the dataframe. Here I could not use them otherwise when I did predict () it gave me error

Comment: if you `print(book.average_rating_converted)`, you will get only 1 number for example `10`, that's why you need to wrap around square brackets like [10] in the dataframe syntax, ie, `pd.DataFrame(data={'key1':[list1], 'key2':[list2]})`

Comment: you should `print(dataframe)` in both cases to compare

Comment: the other code works using square brackets. here instead if I put them it gives me error. if I take them off it works but it prints all of them. The fact is that the prediction only needs to be made for 1 book. What you say is very right, and I have nothing to say, but it is not adaptable to the project because it is not what I asked for. I need a way that if I give the duration and category as input, I only get one book back.

Comment: how about giving the mean of duration and category, so that you can get 1 book back? `dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = {"audioRuntime_converted": [book.audioRuntime_converted.mean()], "category_converted": [book.category_converted.mean()]})` then `model.predict(dataframe)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The solution was simpler than expected. I thank everyone for trying to help me.

The problem was that at the beginning when I do `def_init`, in the parameters I passed `book` instead of `insertedbook`.
It is the same when I create the dataframe